# Controlling Unix IPC signals in npm scripts

Tags: node.js, bash, shell, npm

I'm working on implementing graceful shutdown for a node API. Typically, during development, this process is started using the common `start` script, but I have noticed that this causes some annoying behavior that I'm surprised I've never really noticed before in my 3 or so years as a node developer.

To begin shutdown during development, we simply hit ctrl+C in the bash terminal, which of course causes a `SIGINT` to be sent to the npm process and all of its child processes. I can capture this with a `process.on` handler to initiate a graceful shutdown from there-- closing off new requests, waiting for existing requests to finish, then killing the database connection, all that good stuff.

However, if the developer hits ctrl+C a second time, npm behaves differently. It seems to be sending a SIGTERM to the `sh` process it used to invoke my `start` script in the first place. This causes that `sh` process to print out `Terminated` and exit, returning control of the terminal to the user without waiting for the node process to exit.

This is really annoying because it gives the impression that the node process has been stopped, but of course it hasn't. It will continue until shutdown is complete, or it is forcibly killed with something like SIGKILL or SIGQUIT. If it happens to print anything out to the console, it will do so directly in the middle of whatever else the developer might now be running in that terminal.

For a trivial example, try this:

package.json:

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "start": "node index.js"
    }
}
```

index.js:

```js
async function waitForever() {
    while(true) {
        console.log('waiting...');
        await new Promise((resolve) => {
            setTimeout(resolve, 5000);
        });
    }
}

process.on('SIGINT', () => {
    console.log('SIGINT recieved');
});

process.on('SIGTERM', () => {
    console.log('SIGTERM recieved');
})

waitForever();
```

Run `npm start` in your terminal, then hit ctrl+c once. You'll see the signal make it through to node, but of course it won't exit. Now, do it a second time. You'll see the signal make it through again, but then you immediately see "Terminated" followed by your shell prompt. Until you find the process ID of the node process and kill it with `kill -9` you'll keep seeing that `waiting...` message every five seconds.

I did some more fiddling around with this example and it very much seems like npm is completely responsible for this. If you send `kill -2` directly to the npm process twice, the termination of the shell process occurs, without SIGINT ever being received by the node process.

So I have two main questions:

1. What the heck is going on here? Am I missing something about how my shell works, or is this some kind of feature built in to npm run-script? If so, where I can find information about this? `npm help run-script` shows nothing about it.
2. I know that `start` scripts are pretty common in projects like this, so it seems like someone else should be encountering this problem. How do people typically deal with it? I've Googled around a bunch and it's been hard to find a clear answer.

This isn't a huge deal, of course. The start script is just a convenience to make sure a TS compilation runs before starting up. I can have developers run the built app directly in their shell after building, or write a script that performs the build and start outside of an npm script. But it would be nice to not have to do this.

Really I'm just puzzled and would appreciate some assistance. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To answer your **1** - looking at `npm` code this is expected behavior of handling `SIGINT`. First occurrence of signal is passed down to child process and also attaches one-time listener for subsequent `SIGINT` that will kill the `npm` parent process immediately. You can see code [here](https://github.com/npm/npm-lifecycle/blob/e2270ff3fd49ca8d0af2af13d404e60e296b4244/index.js#L373).

I assume this is because `npm start` is meant as development stage shorthand only and there it makes sense to have a "handbrake" to kill process immediately in cases where you e.g. get signal handling wrong (unfortunately even that doesn't work in all cases as you found out).

I don't have answer for **2** but sometime ago there was a lengthy debate about this going in various `npm` issues regarding signal handling and `npm start`. [Official NPM statement](https://github.com/kimmobrunfeldt/concurrently/issues/4#issuecomment-172645277) was mostly that `npm start` is not replacement for proper process manager (e.g. supervisor or systemd) and shouldn't be used in production environment like that.

EDIT: An answer for **2** from sripberger:

What I ended up doing follows. `shutdown` is a function that performs the shutdown, returning a promise. The first SIGINT will begin the shutdown, but a second will forcibly kill the process whether or not shutdown is finished. This does not prevent npm from terminating the shell process, but it does make sure the node process dies with it when this happens:

```
process.once('SIGINT', () => {
    console.log('\nShutting down, please wait...');

    // Begin the graceful shutdown.
    shutdown().catch((err) => {
        console.error('Could not shut down gracefully:', err);
    });

    // Attach a subsequent handler to force kill.
    process.on('SIGINT', () => {
        console.log('\nProcess killed.');
        process.exit(0);
    });
});
```

Of course, as noted by blami, it is not recommended to use npm scripts to control services in production. This is simply a convenience for development environments.

Comment: Awesome, this is great information that more than answers my first question. Of course, my plan is to use a proper process manager in production, I just feel it is worth it to try to avoid making developers deal with orphaned processes. If we can maybe get an edit in here from someone about whether node developers have come up with some convention for this situation, I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: For example, I noticed that a popular static http server does it's on subsequent SIGINT handler: https://github.com/zeit/serve/blob/6eac67989a8f6ee3a6e1f8bbbff16f39a5fa0aeb/bin/serve.js#L444